# How do I configure Python IDLE's text font?

Tags: python, fonts, python-idle

I've searched all over and can't seem to find a solution. Python's IDLE just looks terrible on my laptop (Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro) with a 3200x1800 display running 8.1

I've attached a screenshot so you can see what I'm talking about. Has anyone figured out how to configure this? Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking IDLE just isn't designed to handle very high res displays and so the OS is scaling it up in a sort of brute force way.

Comment: @Alan IDLE has nothing to do with handling display resolution.  It uses tkinter which uses the tcl/tk gui framework.  Resolution, in turn, has nothing to do with font choice either.  Tk's default font *on Windows* is the Courier shown in the image.

Answer (score 1):

Add a file like `%USERPROFILE%\.idlerc\config-main.cfg`

Add the following lines:

```
[EditorWindow]
font-size = 14
font = monaco
```

Or pick your favorite font and size.

Comment: Using the Options dialog (see my answer) lets one easily see what a font looks like, including fixed versus variable pitch, easily switch between fonts and sizes, and avoids the possibility of user error in hand-editing.

Answer (score 1):

I presume 'terrible looking' applies to the old Courier (typewriter) font.  IDLE's tk Text windows (Shell, Editor, and Output) default to using 10 point 'TkFixedFont'.  On Windows, (and only on Windows), that resolves to 'Courier'.  I believe that this is or at least used to be standard on Windows.

The best solution is to select `Options` on the top menu bar and then `Configure IDLE`.  One is then presented with a dialog with the `Fonts/Tabs` tab selected and the current font selected in the `Base Editor Font` box and the current size next to `Size`.   There is an example box showing some text in the current font and size.  Change either the font or size and the example is updated.  Select `OK` or `Apply` and current text windows are updated.

Choices other than default are written to `config-main.cfg` in directory `%USERPROFILE%/.idlerc/`.  The directory and file are created if necessary.

I personally use the fixed-pitch Lucida Console.  I occasionally use variable-pitch Lucida Sans Unicode when using strings with non-Latin characters.  One can tell from the example in the box whether a font is fixed or variable in character width by whether characters line up neatly in columns or not.  (One of my goals is to add examples from several other scripts so one can also see the unicode coverage offered by a font.)